# How to search Firestore database to find all fields with the same name and key assigned key in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to search Firestore Database to find all Fields ExeName
like it is underscored on this screen:

[image: FireStore database]

and find arrays setnumber with the same key as underscored ExeName Field

[This is my DataModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILJ9R.png)

I was searching a lot of time and can't find anything about that

Comment: What have you tried?  What exact difficulties are you facing?  Please read [ask].  Are all of the documents in the same collection or are they across multiple collections?  Why do you need to search by the string value?  Don't you store the id somewhere?

Comment: Instead of dictionaries you should be using models and collections. It will be much simpler to query items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found idea to fetch all data to my project and then search for the specified string and its key to find corresponding field with the same key value using this function:

```
func searchAndUpdate(searchString: String) {
       let sevenDaysInSeconds: TimeInterval = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
       let currentDate = Date()
       let sevenDaysAgo = currentDate.addingTimeInterval(-sevenDaysInSeconds)
       
       for (index, data) in info.enumerated() {
           for (key, value) in data.ExeName {
               if value == searchString {
                  
                   if let weightArray = data.weight[key], data.time > sevenDaysAgo.timeIntervalSince1970 {
                       let summary = Summary(Name: data.ExeName[key] ?? "",
                                             weig: weightArray,
                                             interval: data.time)
                       chartData.append(summary)
                       
                    
                    break
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is JavaScript(ish), but should be nearly identical in Swift:

```js
const valueToSearchFor = "Dumbbell Seated Scaption";

const myCollRef = collection(db, "some_collection");

const q = query(myCollRef,
                where("ExeName", "array-contains", valueToSearchFor),
                limit(1));

const querySnap = await getDocs(q);
const docSnap = querySnap.docs[0]; // pull out the first result
const theData = docSnap.data();

// find the position of `valueToSearchFor` in the "ExeName" field:
const position = theData.ExeName.indexOf(valueToSearchFor);

// get the "numberreps" array entry for corresponding `valueToSearchFor`
const numberRepsArray = theData.numberreps[position];

console.log("number of reps:", numberRepsArray);
```